# Is there a Magento extension for combining/compressing javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, magento, compression

I thought Magento came with this feature out of the box but it doesn't appear to be working at all. I'm not sure if I haven't set it up properly, but right now I'm resorting to using `cat` and altering the `page.xml` layout file to use the combined javascript and css files.

Can I make Magento do this instead or is there an extension that adds this feature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to System>Configuration>Developer and alter the settings in the Javascript and CSS settings boxes.  Ensure that you have correct Configuration Scope set in the top-left of the page for your website/store.

Make sure that you flush the cache after changing the setting.

P.S. The Fooman Speedster extension will also perform this task.

Comment: Here, it breaks the presentation : all CSS and JS are unreachable, they are not merged and their URLs are their filepaths. Making admin unusable (that's where unobstrusive JS should come into play !!)

Comment: check that your /media folder is writeable (777). Magento needs to be able to write the merged CSS/JS files into the media folder

Answer (score 5):

There is also [mod_pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105441/mod-pagespeed-magento) which does this for all output from your server but doesn't hurt Magento while it does it.

Answer (score 2):

There are extensions in Magento Connect like [JS/CSS Compression minify](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/js-css-compression-and-minify-user-interface-optimization.html) or on the web like [Compressor](http://www.luigifab.info/magento/compressor.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/10581

this extension works fine and has improved our site's performances to a considerably higher levels...

Think this might help someone...

Answer (score 0):

install `mod_pagespeed` by [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download) on server zero configuration for your magento.