# Magento minimize varien js files -- is this ok?

Tags: magento, enterprise, minimize, mage

I am minimizing my javascript files in my magento build to optimize page load time.  I already minimized the skin/frontend/THEME/default/js files that were large, and next on my list are the varien javascript files.

My question is: Is it harmful to minimize the varien javascript files since they are technically part of Magento's core?  I will obviously save backups of uncompressed files.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Magento extension for combining/compressing javascript and css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236381/is-there-a-magento-extension-for-combining-compressing-javascript-and-css)

Comment: That post is helpful, but the fooman speedster extension is not offered for enterprise edition and so I was hoping to tweak performance on my own and wondered if doing this task would damage something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing the CSS and JS should have no side effects, that being said I have seen it screw up some of my style sheets before.  Best approach is to enable each one by one in an testing environment and make sure everything looks and functions properly and look for any JS errors.  Fooman speedster does the same thing that is built-in now with Magento.

If you encounter any issues disable the merging, your original files (JS/CSS) will be retained and are not modified, they are simply processed and combined into a *new* single file, so to answer your question it will not harm any core files by enabling such feature.

Comment: The built in merge feature doesn't minify files, it only concatenates them.

Comment: @clockworkgeek, good to know, I was under the assumption it minified and combined.

Comment: I had assumed the same until I actually looked at one of the served files and saw the comments were intact.